# Spring Boot Security - Use token from Cookies if Authorization header missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I currently authenticate my requests against the JWK of my authorization server.
I'm using the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` package on spring-boot 2.3.
The JWT is taken out from the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header and validated against the JWK endpoint.
My security config looks like this:

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  protected Environment env;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/logs").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/api/**").authenticated();
    http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://auth.work.com/v1/jwk
```

External users don't have the `Authorization: ...` header in their requests, but instead have the following 2 cookies that make up the JWT:

```
auth.token_type = Bearer
auth.access_token = <token>
```

Is there a way to extract the JWT from the cookies and validate against the auth server if the the `Authorization: ...` header is missing?
Could I extract the cookies and add a header to the request before it tries to authorize?
Or it could even be a second method in the authentication chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `@Component` annotated class implementing the `BearerTokenResolver` interface:

```java
@Override
public String resolve(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "YOUR_COOKIE_NAME");
    if (cookie != null)
        return cookie.getValue();
    else
        return new DefaultBearerTokenResolver().resolve(request);
}
```

This way, Spring will not create an instance of the default `DefaultBearerTokenResolver` implementation, which you can still reuse if needed in your overridden `resolve` method, to retrieve the token from the header.

Greetings.

Comment: That's perfect! This didn't exist back in the days but I'll mark it as the answer now.

Answer (score 15):

I found out about custom token resolvers and ended up creating one to validate both the header and the cookie. I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution, but it works.

The only issue I have with this is that it doesn't automatically validate the `Authorization: Bearer ...` header anymore, so I had to add the code for it too.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/logs").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/api/**").authenticated();
    http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().and().bearerTokenResolver(this::tokenExtractor);
  }

  public String tokenExtractor(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (header != null)
      return header.replace("Bearer ", "");
    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "auth.access_token");
    if (cookie != null)
      return cookie.getValue();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use Custom Filter, intercept request and fetch cookies from HttpServletRequest.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(
  ServletRequest request, 
  ServletResponse response,
  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    // Your validation logic
}
```

Just add it to Spring Security filters chain.

More details how to do it here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter